# Вживання слів "рождений", "народжений" та "роджений"

Tags: вживання-слів, вибір-слова

У колядці "[Бог ся рождає](https://nashe.com.ua/song/9943)" зустрічаємо такі слова:

"*Тут ангели чудяться,
**Рожденного** бояться,
А віл стоїть трясеться,
Осел смутно пасеться*"

В СУМі такого слова немає, але там є "[роджений](http://sum.in.ua/s/rodzhenyj)" із позначкою "діал.".

Однак, в Інтернеті набагато частіше зустрічається слово "[народжений](http://sum.in.ua/s/narodzhenyj)", наприклад: [новонароджений](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9), а також [незаконнонароджений](http://sum.in.ua/s/nezakonnonarodzhenyj).

Цікавить те чи можна таким же чином утворити слова новорожденний, назаконнорождений або ж новороджений та незаконороджений? А також чи слово "рождений" є діалектним (бо колядка слова якої я навів на початку часто зустрічається в західній частині України) чи калькою від російського "[рождённый](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)".

Comment: “рождений” в заголовку написано двічі. поредаґуйте, будь ласка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У Словнику Грінченка є слово [рождати](http://hrinchenko.com//slovar/znachenie-slova/51186-rozhdaty.html), що посилає на [рожати](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/51184-rozhaty.html). Тобто "... рожденного бояться" означає народженого. В той час *рождений* має інше значення:

> Рождений, -а, -е. Прирожденный. Рождена відьма. ХС. VII. 449. Відьми є рождені і вчені. Драг. 68

Оскільки *народжений* і *рожденний* є синонімами, тому як і від слова *народжений*, так і від *рожденний* можна утворити слова префіксальним способом.
*Рожденний* не є калькою з російської, бо використовується у назві шевченківського твору ["І МЕРТВИМ, І ЖИВИМ, І НЕНАРОЖДЕННИМ ЗЕМЛЯКАМ МОЇМ В УКРАЙНІ І НЕ В УКРАЙНІ МОЄ ДРУЖНЄЄ ПОСЛАНІЄ"](http://litopys.org.ua/shevchenko/shev140.htm).

Слова *рождати* та *рождений* є архаїзмами оскільки вийшли з загального ужитку та були замінені на *народжувати* та *природжений*. Зроблю припущення, що
ці слова мають старослов'янське походження ([джерело](http://litopys.org.ua/hrushukr/hrush411.htm)).